# Vim: converting matching parenthesis to matching curly braces

Tags: vim

I saw a screencast where someone had highlighted a set of parenthesis and instantly converted them to curly braces. Is this a macro or a Vim thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can do it with surround.vim plugin.  https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround

e.g.

when your cursor (`*`) at : `( fo*o)`, press `cs({` will change your text into `{ fo*o}`

Answer (score 2):

They use vim [surround plugin](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround).

Quoting their Hello World.

> It's easiest to explain with examples. Press `cs"'` inside
>
> > "Hello world!"
>
> to change it to
>
> > 'Hello world!'